# jQuery success function not returning message from servlet response

Tags: java, jquery

I am creating a login page using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), `servlet` but I can not seem to reading the response returned,when the response is true it must go to the `success.jsp` page but it does not, I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong please help.
Here my:

**js**:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "LoginServlet",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        var xhr = data.msg;
        if (xhr === "true") {
          alert(xhr);
          window.location.href = "success.jsp";

        } else {
          alert(xhr);
        }
      }
```

**my servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
      LoginDAO dao = new LoginDAO();
      String username=request.getParameter("username");
      String password=request.getParameter("passsword");
      String msg = "false";




       Login login = dao.validateUser(username, password);

             String username1 = login.getUsername();
             String password1 = login.getPassword();
       if(LoginDAO.isEqual(username, password1) && LoginDAO.isEqual(password, password1)){

                msg = "true";

       }


       response.setContentType("text/plain");
       response.getWriter().write(msg);


   }
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btnlogin').click(function(e){
 
  
   var username = $('#username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  
 
  $.ajax({
   url: "LoginServlet",
   type: "post",
   data: {"username":username,"password":password},
   cache: false,
   success: function (data){
    var xhr = data.msg;
    if(xhr === "true"){
      alert(xhr);
    window.location.href="success.jsp" ;
    
   }
   else
    {
     alert(xhr);
    }
   }
  }); 
 
 });
});

Comment: Please edit the question; don't put that much code into a comment.

Comment: add an error callback in your js code, to see if it is reached...

Comment: Please specify what are you getting as of now. And use browser development tool to debug your request/response.

Comment: It stays in the same page...It is suppose to go to the next

Comment: Your response is text/plain. Try: success: function (data){
            var xhr = data;
            if(xhr === "true"){
                 alert(xhr);
            window.location.href="success.jsp" ;
        }

Comment: Change: «var xhr = data.msg;» to «var xhr = data;».

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this code:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().write(msg);
```

Sets a response type `text/plain` with a value: `true` or `false`.

Then, in your jQuery.ajax() function change `var xhr = data.msg;` to `var xhr = data;`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "LoginServlet",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    },
    dataType: "text", // To match with the actual response type: «text/plain».
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var xhr = data; // Because «data» contains true or false.
        if (xhr === "true") {
            alert(xhr);
            window.location.href = "success.jsp";

        } else {
            alert(xhr);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have directly assigned username & password, but you should get them from UI.
Modify your client code as below:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
      var username = "admin";
      var password = "admin";
      $.ajax({
        url: "LoginServlet",
        type: "post",
        data: {
          "username": username,
          "password": password
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("data: " + data);
          var xhr = data;
          console.log("xhr: " + xhr);
          if (data == "true") {
            alert(xhr);
            window.location.href = "success.jsp";

          } else {
            alert(xhr);
          }
        }
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

And you misspelled password to passsword, please correct it

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```

Comment: @user3576758 You should accept and upvote the answer if it has helped you in getting off your issue